# Remove scala version from publishing path

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm trying to deploy my sbt plugin to azure artifacts. Sbt adds the scala version to publishing path like in:

https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/orgname/projectname/_packaging/feed/maven/v1/com/test/plugin-name_2.12_1.0/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/plugin-name-0.0.1.pom

Azure artifacts replies with a 400. I'm quite sure that's because of the added scala version. Is there a way remove the scala version from the path?

I read the documentation, looked up examples, but didn't find a solution.

Comment: Considering that all conventions assume that this suffix is there, and Maven, Sonatype, and in the past also Bintray all accepted this convention, devops are asking you to make this a problem for you and your users. From what I see this is about sbt plugin, sooo, you will have to have a dedicated instruction about adding it to sbt since normal `addPlugin("orgname" % "projectname" % "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT")` will expect to find it under the path with added suffix.

Comment: Maybe explain why people are not happy with this path? I have a hard time understanding why anyone would matter about this.

Comment: Re: why they'd be unhappy, there is relevant background at https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/3410